# kubectl port-forward fails when I change the port numbers

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm following a book and they have this config for an app

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demo
          image: cloudnatived/demo:hello
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8888

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  # NOTE: depending on which version of the book you have, this may say port 9999. The latest version of the book uses 8888 to match the pod.
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8888
  selector:
    app: demo
  type: ClusterIP
```

This works properly.

```
kubectl port-forward service/demo 9999:8888
>>> Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9999 -> 8888
Forwarding from [::1]:9999 -> 8888
Handling connection for 9999
```

```
curl localhost:9999/info 
>>> Hello, 世界
```

---

But if I change the container ports it doesn't work.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demo
          image: cloudnatived/demo:hello
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9278

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  # NOTE: depending on which version of the book you have, this may say port 9999. The latest version of the book uses 8888 to match the pod.
  ports:
  - port: 4269
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9278
  selector:
    app: demo
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
kubectl port-forward service/demo 9999:4269
>>> Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9999 -> 9278
Forwarding from [::1]:9999 -> 9278
Handling connection for 9999
E1117 15:59:19.151771   38005 portforward.go:409] an error occurred forwarding 9999 -> 9278: error forwarding port 9278 to pod 0c928b279bf1932972fc6724a22d8dac57ebb89696569269868959a342072b24, uid : container not running (0c928b279bf1932972fc6724a22d8dac57ebb89696569269868959a342072b24)
error: lost connection to pod
```

```
curl localhost:9999/info
>>> curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I am not sure why this is failing. As I understand it, when you do
`kubectl port-forward service/demo 9999:4269` it forwards my local port 9999 to the port in the pod 9278, via the port 4269 on the service.

I have tried this multiple times with the same result. The moment I switch everything back to 8888 everything works fine.

Comment: It sounds like the process inside the Pod is listening on port 8888; what inside the Pod is listening on port 9278?

Comment: I thought specifying `containerPort: 9278` makes the pod listen to 9278. Is that not the case?

Comment: It doesn't change anything about what the _process_ is doing; if you haven't reconfigured the _process_ to listen on a different port then the mismatched `containerPort:` will cause this problem.  In practice, the container port is only used as a target for its matching Service so it doesn't really matter what that port number is.

Comment: By reconfigure the process, do you mean apply the changes? That I do using `kubectl apply -f k8s/app.yaml` after I change the port numbers. And I have verfied it too. `kubectl describe pod/POD_NAME` gives `Port: 9278/TCP`. `kubectl describe service/SERVICE_NAME` gives `Port: <unset>  4269/TCP` and `TargetPort: 9278/TCP`

Comment: Inside the Pod is a container, inside the container is a process, and that process has some set of command-line arguments and configuration files.  The _process_ doesn't know about the Kubernetes-level configuration; if you set `containerPort: 9278` but the process is still listening on port 8888 then things won't work.

Comment: If the container port is not directly related to the application port, how does it know to listen on 8888? Is it because when I first created the pod I specified 8888? And how do I access and/or change the application port?

Comment: That's application-specific.  Maybe it has a command-line argument that could go into `args:`, or maybe you need to inject a file via a ConfigMap.  There's no particular reason to need to change it in most cases, though.

Answer (score 1):

in yaml specification,

```yaml
image: cloudnatived/demo:hello
ports:
   - containerPort: 8888
```

means you use `coludnatived/demo:hello` and expose 8888 port as deployment. see
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/connect-applications-service/#exposing-pods-to-the-cluster

> Note that the containers are not using port 80 on the node, nor are there any special NAT rules to route traffic to the pod. This means you can run multiple nginx pods on the same node all using the same containerPort, and access them from any other pod or node in your cluster using the assigned IP address for the pod.

In your example, you use replica and three containers which exposing 9278 port load balancer(In your case Service) can touch it.
It does not mean your application image listening 9278.

but Ironically, in docs(https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#container-v1-core)

> ports: List of ports to expose from the container. Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be accessible from the network. Modifying this array with strategic merge patch may corrupt the data. For more information See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/108255. Cannot be updated.

How can I clarify this, I want to show some example with below 9278 option.
Run this CLI.

```
kubectl get pods

--- pods showed ---
 
kubectl port-forward [anypod] 9999:8888
```

even your deployment container ports set to 9278, but pod can be access with 8888 and accessible.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. But why am I unable to access the service on port 9278?

Comment: first, you need to change container image service port If you want to listen 9278. building new image. 
but If you think once again, Indeed you don't need to. 
Just play with default Nginx image to this issue for convenience.

Comment: I do build a new image using `kubectl apply -f k8s/app.yaml` after I change the port numbers. It still doesn't work.

Comment: And I have verfied it too. `kubectl describe pod/POD_NAME` gives `Port: 9278/TCP`. `kubectl describe service/SERVICE_NAME` gives `Port: <unset>  4269/TCP` and `TargetPort: 9278/TCP`

Comment: @VishalBalaji pod port != application listening port. pod is set of container. and I said container port in yaml file(exists or not exists) does NOT prevent that port from being exposed (explained above).

Comment: I think I kind of get it now. I have 2 more question. 1. How do I access and change the application port? 2. Why does 8888 work if the pod port is not the same as the application port? Is it some kind of default?

Comment: @VishalBalaji 1. How do I access and change the application port? -> `change web app source code and build its image` 2. Why does 8888 work if the pod port is not the same as the application port? Is it some kind of default? -> as docs said.`Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be accessible from the network.`